# Integration $\int \left(x-\frac{1}{2x} \right)^2\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int\!\left(x-\frac{1}{2x} \right)^2\,dx. $$

Using integrating by substitution, I got $u=x-\frac{1}{2x},\quad \dfrac{du}{dx} =1+ \frac{1}{2x^2}$ , and $dx= 1+2x^2 du$. In the end, I came up with the answer to the integral as :
$$\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2x^2}{3}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{2x}\right)^3.$$

Any mistake ?

Comment: $dx$ is not $(1+2x^2)\,du$.

Comment: can you show me the correction please, and thanks William, for pointing that out.

Comment: $dx=\frac{2x^2}{2x^2+1}\,du$, which doesn't see useful, since when we substitute, **everything** has to be expressed in terms of $u$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just expand
$$
\left(x-\frac{1}{2x}\right)^2 = x^2 - 1 +\frac{1}{4x^2}
$$
and integrate term by term.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the square bracket and integrating each term individually gives 
\begin{equation*}
\int (x-\frac{1}{2x})^2dx=\int (x^2+\frac{1}{4x^2}-1)dx=\int x^2dx+\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{x^2}dx-\int dx\\
=\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{1}{4x}-x+C
\end{equation*}
for a constant $C$.